# How to merge a series of objects in jmespath

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I get an array of results after performing an `include_vars` with `with_items`

```
results:
- ansible_facts:
    tag_Cluster_A:
      name: Thinking cluster
      words:
      - Honk
      - Thonk
- ansible_facts:
    tag_Cluster_B:
      name: Helloing Cluster
      words:
      - HOI
      - HOI HOI
```

I'm trying to get the object with the results to a flat object that just contains the `tag_Cluster_*` things.

```
tag_Cluster_A:
  name: Thinking cluster
  words:
  - Honk
  - Thonk
tag_Cluster_B:
  name: Helloing Cluster
  words:
  - HOI
  - HOI HOI
```

The query `results[].ansible_facts` results in an array like:
 `[{tag_Cluster_A:{}},{tag_Cluster_B:{}}]` which is 1 step away from the desired outcome.

How do I smoosh these together?

Comment: @techraf no, I want to do what would normally be something like `reduce` in other languages.

Comment: So it is just not possible? I do not believe this is a duplicate question since it's asking for a different transformation of the data than the linked question, even if the answer is applicable to both (go around jmespath).

The difference between the questions is remapping the keys and values, which I don't want to do. Given something like `[{a:1},{b:2}]` I wish to produce `{a:1, b:2}`

Comment: I don't understand how to perform this transformation within jmespath, which is why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

If `mylist` is `[{tag_Cluster_A:{...}},{tag_Cluster_B:{...}}]`, then

```
mydict: "{{ dict(mylist | map('dictsort') | sum(start=[])) }}"
```

will be `{tag_Cluster_A:{...},tag_Cluster_B:{...}}`.

In this trick we apply `dictsort` filter to every element of original list, then flatten the list to get single list of pairs, then convert it back into dict.

Comment: Booo, not JMESpath ;-)

Comment: Yeah. Until [this](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/pull/105) is merged, JMESpath is rather reduced in dict manipulation. Or my [patched](https://gist.github.com/berlic/3b733390901625092796c7871d8fc23b) json_query can be used with `to_entries`/`from_entries`.

Comment: It is an unfortunate state of affairs. I've decided to write a reduce filter plugin for now but will be monitoring it.